# Twitter URL to create a thread, not just single tweet

Tags: twitter

On Twitter, HTML links like `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world` open the “create new tweet” page for a user with that text (here “Hello world”) prefilled. The user can tweet that text with one click. (cf. [twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview))

Is it possible to do this, but for twitter thread? i.e. a URL which has several tweets already filled in, where the user can click once to create the thread.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Twitter web intents do not provide this feature.